# Hide totals detail in categorized view in XPages?

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel displaying a view.  The view has a total column in front of a categorized column that shows the total for that category.  How can I not show the number when it is on the detail line?

Comment: Why not to make another view without totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the below Xpage view column formula, according to your totals column name.

```
viewEntry.isDocument()? '' : viewEntry.getColumnValue('<totalColumnName>')
```

where viewEntry is the request variable scope name under which row data made available.

Comment: This only sort of works.    There are two issues. 1. An extra twistee now shows up  on the total count as well as the product name, even though they untwist the same thing. 2. There is no total of all of the categories shown.

Comment: I swapped the count column with the categorized column and that eliminated the extra "twistee".   I also tried viewEntry.isCategory() || viewEntry.isTotal() ? viewEntry.getColumnValue('count') : "" as my formula which, I would think should work but it still does not show the total.

Comment: It looks like viewEntry.isTotal()   is never true when it is used in a column formula.

Comment: I looked at this again and even without your formula and just displaying the count column, the total does not even display there.  I think the totals not displaying has to do with the fact that I am filtering by category.   Sort of makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the view move the totals column behind the categories and use the property to hide details. The column sequence in the view and in the view panel don't need to be the same. So you can move it back in front in the panel.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you.  When you say "behind", if you mean to the right of the categories then that did not make a difference.  I still get two twistees.  And to clarify the count twistee expands the same line as the category twistee.

Comment: Can you post the DXL of the view? The count should neither be sorted nor categorized and the property "show twisties" must not be set

Comment: The count is neither sorted nor categorized.

Answer (score 0):

Using this technique does not work for me using r10 FP6 and Chrome version 90.

Total column behaves as a  UI-only notes column function, and thus throws an error with a viewPanel column formula like *return view1.isDocument()?'':view1.getColumnValue('totCol1');*

Simply binding the viewPanel Column to the notes (total) column works, but the detail rows ('1's) are not ignored.